# "OAS_validation_error" paypal

Tags: javascript, paypal

I have used a standard Paypal express checkout button for my website however, upon inputting credit/debit card details customers keep getting 'OAS_validation_error'.

The checkout was working fine for the initial weeks (I made over 50 transactions during testing) but abruptly stopped working for a few months now. I have contacted Paypal several times but I keep getting referred to different teams with no solution.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
<!-- Add meta tags for mobile and IE -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title> PayPal Checkout Integration | Client Demo </title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
 <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

 <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client- 
      id=test&currency=USD"></script>

      <script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: '88.44'
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                console.log('Capture result', orderData, 
              JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                var transaction = 
               orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + 
             transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available 
  details');

                // Replace the above to show a success message within 
          this page, e.g.
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal- 
             button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment! 
            </h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  
         actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
          }


         }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        </script>
          </body>

         </html>
```

The json response:
{"errors":[{"data":[{"code":"EXISTING_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED"}],"message":"OAS_VALIDATION_ERROR","path":["approveGuestPaymentWithCreditCard"],"checkpoints":["onboard_user"],"meta":{},"contingency":true,"statusCode":200}],"data":{"approveGuestPaymentWithCreditCard":null},"extensions":{"tracing":{"version":1,"startTime":"2021-11-30T02:41:12.584Z","endTime":"2021-11-30T02:41:12.837Z","duration":252644113,"execution":{"resolvers":[{"path":["approveGuestPaymentWithCreditCard"],"parentType":"Mutation","fieldName":"approveGuestPaymentWithCreditCard","returnType":"CheckoutSession","startOffset":1454344,"duration":250581192}]}},"correlationId":"f2593514582c8"}}

Comment: Your question definitely needs more information about the problem behavior that occurs ("keep getting 'OAS_validation_error'." has no context and so is nowhere near specific and detailed enough) -- and probably also runnable code that could reproduce the issue, since the code you've included is not runnable

Comment: @PrestonPHX Thanks for reaching out. The checkout seems to be working on the sandbox account but does not work in production. I provided the code above as a reference but to go through the whole check out experience you would have to create a Paypal business account. I seem to be not the only one that is having this issue https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/1224

Comment: Apparently the issue is a credit card decline, but without more details can't offer any useful comment as to why

Comment: @PrestonPHX   I am purchasing from the UK and what kind of further information do you want me to provide?

Comment: A sample with a complete log of the error. Your question should also be clear in specifying when it occurs.

Comment: @PrestonPHX here is the link for the code above https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: @PrestonPHX I have also included the error log image above

Comment: @PrestonPHX As mentioned earlier you may need to create a business account to get the AppID. Just to reiterate my checkout button works for the sandbox development account but not when using the live production app id

Comment: The entire JSON of the network response is not visible in what you added

Comment: @PrestonPHX I have uploaded the response  json file. Also, I want to add that I have already called up Paypal customer service and my bank branch to ask if my card was being  blocked but both said they hadn't blocked it.  the issue seems to be coming from the express checkout itself

Answer (score 0):

The most telling part of the error is `EXISTING_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTED`. This is a credit card decline by PayPal, apparently due to the account being flagged for unauthorized fraud. Perhaps because you attempted to pay yourself in PayPal's live environment, which is not permitted -- credit card companies expressly forbid processing any payments to yourself.

If you contact PayPal's customer support and give them the number to the affected card, they might be able to unblock it in the PayPal environment, but meanwhile this error is expected behavior when using that card to make a payment anywhere with PayPal.

If you need to test live payments in the future, make sure the card you are using to make the payment and the account being used to receive the payment are not associated in **any** way (no names or addresses or phone numbers or email used during checkout in common, etc)